# Cannot read property when use permission.remove()

Tags: javascript, permissions, geolocation

I want remove geolocation permission in my website

https://developer.chrome.com/apps/permissions

```
 chrome.permissions.remove({
      permissions: ['geolocation'],
  }, function(removed) {
      if (removed) {
          // The permissions have been removed.
      } else {
          // The permissions have not been removed (e.g., you tried to remove
          // required permissions).
      }
  });
```

I get this errorL

> Cannot read property 'remove' of undefined

My `manifest.json`:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Permissions Example",
  "description": "Permissions Example",
  "version": "1.0",
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "geolocation"
  ],
  "optional_permissions": [
    "history"
  ]
}
```

Add to project:

```
<link href="manifest.json" rel="manifest">
```

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. Change your manifest so geolocation is option, not required, otherwise you won't be able to remove the permission:

```
    {
      "manifest_version": 2,
      "name": "Permissions Example",
      "description": "Permissions Example",
      "version": "1.0",
      "permissions": [
        "tabs"
      ],
      "optional_permissions": [
        "history",
        "geolocation"
      ]
    }
```

2. [chrome.permissions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/permissions) can only be called from your options, popup or background page, not from a content script. And the call must be initiated from a user action, so if you want to do this from a content script, you will have to use [chrome.runtime.sendMessage()](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) to communicate between your client script and your background script.

Answer (score -1):

you can remove with delete operator https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete, for example

```js
const permission = {
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Permissions Example",
  "description": "Permissions Example",
  "version": "1.0",
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "geolocation"
  ],
  "optional_permissions": [
    "history"
  ]
}

delete permission.permissions
console.log(permission)
```

Comment: Thanks for the post but this is not the correct answer to my question
Please refer to this link.https://developer.chrome.com/apps/permissions